# ¿Cómo combinar comandos con grep y sort?

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos, gnu

Tengo un archivo con un conjunto de nombres, de los cuales quiero solo tienes los nombres que contengan la letra "p". Esto se haría con un:

`grep p "archivo"`

Pero adicional a ello deseo que este resultado salga en el orden inverso, esto se haría con:

`grep p "archivo" | sort -r`

Y luego a este resultado deseo guardarlo en un nuevo archivo con otro  nombre; es en este paso donde me confundo porque no sé qué operador ponerle y cómo escribir el sort para que se guarde en otro archivo. Sí sé que es el símbolo ">" pero no sé cómo es la escritura después de todos esos pasos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes que usar es una redirección. Igual que usaste `|` para enviar la salida de un proceso a la entrada de otro, `>` sirve para enviar la salida de un proceso a un archivo.

```
grep foo | sort bar > el-archivo
```

Si desearas hacer *append* (o sea, no comenzar el archivo desde 0 sino agregar mas contenido al existente), usarías `>>`. Esto, por cierto, no es algo de grep, o sort. Es also de los interpretes de comandos que se puede usar con cualquier proceso o *filtro*. Por ejemplo, quiero arrancar una aplicación hecha en java y que lo que ella ponga en el terminal lo guarde en un archivo:

```
java blah blah blah > el-log.txt
```